# Apply family of functions in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a double loop in this form:

```
for (j in 1:col(mat))
{
    for (i in 1:nrow(mat))
    {
       decision[i][j] = ifelse(mat[i][j] > 3, 1, 0)
    }
}
```

Is there any way this functionality can be achieved through one of the apply functions with significantly improved speed?

Comment: Also, to access the ith row and jth column of a `matrix` (or `data.frame`) in R, you need to do `[i, j]` not `[i][j]`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any loops. If you create a matrix that looks like this

```
mat<-matrix(sample(1:10, 5*7, replace=T), ncol=7)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,]    9    6   10    7    6   10    6
#[2,]    7    6    3    3    6    8    3
#[3,]    7    9    7    5    6    7    6
#[4,]    2    3    8    6   10    1    5
#[5,]    4    1    5    6    1   10    6
```

then you can just do

```
decision <- (mat>3)+0
decision;
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    1    1    0    0    1    1    0
#[3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#[4,]    0    0    1    1    1    0    1
#[5,]    1    0    1    1    0    1    1
```

Comment: To clarify, the `+0` is there in order to change the logical result of `TRUE` and `FALSE` to a numeric one (try it without the `+0` to see).

Answer (score 1):

R is a vectorized language, so for this kind of simple manipulation of a matrix `apply` type functions are not needed, just do:

```
decision <- ifelse(mat > 3, 1, 0)
```

(I'm assuming you want to iterate through the elements of the matrix, which means you would say `ncol(mat)` in your loop; `col` gives something rather different).